# How to make an object appear and disappear at different times in Unity playmode?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I want to make an object in Unity3D that just appears and disappears randomly a few times during play mode at certain times. The time of occurrence of the object is to be determined. With the following code a random cube is displayed and disappears after 3 seconds.
But it should not be visible in the beginning and then appear several times.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Trigger: MonoBehaviour
{
   public GameObject Object;

   void Start()
   {
       StartCoroutine(ShowAndHide());
   }


   IEnumerator ShowAndHide()
   {

        Object.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        Object.SetActive(false);

   }
}
```

Comment: You have not changed this question since you asked it yesterday. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72273778/how-to-make-an-object-appear-and-disappear-at-different-times-with-unity

Answer (score 2):

**You need to create a circle type loop for that. Use this code in your coroutine..**

```
 bool active = true; //if you want a stop this circle then false active value..
     while(active)
            {
              Object.SetActive(!Object.activeSelf); // or activeInHierarchy
              yield return new WaitForSeconds("yourTime"); 
            }
```

***I realise now randomly lol :)***

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(0f,'yourMaxValue'));
```

Comment: I tried it out and modificated my IEnumerate function but it is not working. I set the range until 10 but the Object never appears.